# Would you know a diary with notes template (A5 format)?

Tags: formatting

Would you know a diary with notes template?  Pdflatex and Tikz would be the best to perform this.

It would be great to have the time slots + below/above some place for some notes and priorities.

It could be ideal if it could be printed on two pages so that the printed book has a A5 format, when closed.

Herewith a nice example: 
[image]

Minimal attempt working example:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tgheros,tikz,array}
\usetikzlibrary{calendar}
\begin{document}
\sffamily
\newcommand\daytext[2]{%
  \begin{tabular}{|>{\mdseries\tiny}r|p{1.5cm}|}
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{#1} \\
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{#2\color{black}} \\[1ex]
    \hline
     6:00 & \\\hline
     7:00 & \\\hline
     8:00 & \\\hline\hline
     9:00 & \\\hline
    10:00 & \\\hline
    11:00 & \\\hline
    12:00 & \\\hline\hline
     1:00 & \\\hline
     2:00 & \\\hline\hline
     3:00 & \\\hline
     4:00 & \\\hline
     5:00 & \\\hline
     6:00 & \\\hline\hline
     7:00 & \\\hline
     8:00 & \\\hline
     9:00 & \\\hline\hline
    10:00 & \\\hline
    11:00 & \\\hline
  \end{tabular}
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \calendar (cal)
  [dates=2016-04-17 to 2016-04-23,day list right,day xshift=3cm,
  day text={\daytext{\%wt}{\Huge\%d-}}]%\ooalign{\Huge\%d-\cr\hidewidth\raisebox{1cm}{\%wt}\hidewidth}}]
  if (weekend) [font=\bfseries]
  if (Sunday) [red];
  \node[above right,font=\bfseries\LARGE] at (cal-2016-04-17.north west)
    {April 17--23, 2016};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! What have you tried? Right now this is one humungous do-it-all-for-me. You may get lucky if your question tickles some procrastinator's fancy, but you stand a better chance if you post some code you're working on and ask how to overcome a specific obstacle. Alternatively, consider including ducks in your diary. Or, for best results, combine both strategies.

Comment: Take a look at `tikz-calendar`.

Comment: Do you mean a part of my code that could do it? (link: https://pastebin.com/raw/ejzk8yuj) yeah, but it is not sufficiently clean to be a good basis.

Comment: Something minimal you can post here. Don't rely on external links: you question should remain useful to future users. Edit your question to include the code.